# Avoiding duplicate customer data

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table that produces a row of data holding two customers details that are thought to be the same person. This customer is known by a sourcekey. the table will have scenarios where sourcekey 1 is matched to sourcekey 2 and in the next row, it will match sourcekey 2 to sourcekey 1.

I tried the following to weed out what i call "A-B, B-A matches". This is duplicate as regardless of which is first, it is the same combination. 
I tried;

```
...WHERE SCORES.SOURCEKEY_TO != SCORES.SOURCEKEY_FROM
     AND scores.SOURCEKEY_FROM < scores.SOURCEKEY_TO
```

But i am still coming across duplicates.

Comment: Why do you need this 'AND' clause? AND scores.SOURCEKEY_FROM < scores.SOURCEKEY_TO ? Remove that.

Comment: The first part prevents matches where the two sourcekeys are the same, the second part is intended to prevent the "A-B B-A" match. That is that part that is failing, it does reduce the volume but doesn't prevent them all.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select
distinct
case when SOURCEKEY_TO<SOURCEKEY_FROM then SOURCEKEY_TO else SOURCEKEY_FROM end as SOURCEKEY_FROM, 
case when SOURCEKEY_FROM>SOURCEKEY_TO then SOURCEKEY_FROM else SOURCEKEY_TO end as SOURCEKEY_TO
from scores
where
SOURCEKEY_FROM <> SOURCEKEY_TO
```

Example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fc5c9a017c4c09a6d15254a0a2142915).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try and report back with outcome.

Comment: Thank you very much, This has worked great!!! I just need to work it into a bigger script as sourcekey is only of of approx 40 columns. When i first tried, it only returned the sourcekeys, a little bit of tweaking and i'll figure it out. Thanks again.